# Is the Webbot include method supported in WSS v3?

Tags: 2007, migration, frontpage-rpc

I was given a website which I'm guessing the end client built in Front Page. I was asked to move it to the same client's SharePoint server. The website markup has 3 include statements on each page of the site similar to this:

```
<!--webbot bot="Include" U-Include="includes/header.html" TAG="BODY" -->
```

At first glance they didn't work. However, after some manipulation, I got some of them to work, but not consistently. That really confuses me. I read the KB article on [FrontPage WebBot components](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143090) and it doesn't explain how it could work sometimes and not others.

I don't understand why this webbot syntax works sometimes and not others inside a SharePoint 2007 site.

I know that I could rebuild the site the SharePoint way with a master page, but let's say I want to do it this way for the short term. Can you explain a way I can use it successfully consistently?

Comment: Tom - Are the pages that you moved over on the same web app as SharePoint -- in the _layouts folder, for example?  Or are they in a different web app entirely?

Comment: Rob - I'm asking about support within SharePoint. I've tried document libraries and folders created from SharePoint Designer with mixed results.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this that you can provide?

Comment: No. I moved it to a SharePoint 2007 master page without the webbot tags.